# log4net how to put new line after the footer

Tags: c#, log4net, newline

I have a configuration for log4net as follows:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\...\log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value ="Start new file proccessing..."/>
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date - %message%exception" />
        <footer value ="Finish with the proccessing"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

And it works fine but I wish I could add a new line after my footer, so when I append more than once to my log file the footer from the previous run doesn't stay on the same line with the begining (header) of the second run.

Example:

```
Operation started..
....
Operation endedOperationStarted
....
Operation ended
```

I wish I could make it look like:

```
Operation started..
....
Operation ended
OperationStarted
....
Operation ended
```

Answer (score 12):

Append `&#13;&#10;` to your header / footer value, i.e. `<footer value ="Finish&#13;&#10;"/>`
(see [log4net documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#layout-header-xml-newlines))

Comment: Same here. %newline does not work as expected. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following workaround:

```
<footer type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log finished.%newline" />
```